# Adding Images to JLabels in a panel in Java

Tags: java, image, netbeans, jlabel, imageicon

I am trying to set pictures as icons new JLabels and then add those JLabels to several panels that I created in design view. The program runs fine but non of the pictures or jlabels can be seen.
Here's an example of my code to create labels

```
JLabel J0 = new JLabel();
J0.setIcon(new ImageIcon("4.jpeg"));

JLabel J1 = new JLabel();
J1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("5.jpeg"));

JLabel J2 = new JLabel();
J2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("6.jpeg"));

JLabel J3 = new JLabel();
J3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("7.jpeg"));

JLabel J4 = new JLabel();
J4.setIcon(new ImageIcon("8.jpeg"));

JLabel J5 = new JLabel();
J5.setIcon(new ImageIcon("9.jpeg"));
```

and here is an example of the code to add the JLabels to the panels which I have.

```
p1.add(J1);
p1.add(J2);
p1.add(J3);
p1.add(J4);
p1.add(J5);
p1.add(J6);
p1.add(J7);
p2.add(J8);
p2.add(J9);
p2.add(J10);
```

[image: This is the code in design view, there are 5 panels on the right]
[image: This is the running program, non of the pictures or JLabels can be seen in the panels]

Comment: Where are the pictures saved,means in which directory?

Comment: 1) Follow standard Java naming conventions. Variable names should NOT shart with an upper case character. 2) In you last question you were asked to post an `MCVE` with your question. Again you did not post your MCVE.

Comment: Where are the images stored, relative to the source code? What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the path of all the pictures in your ImageIcon constructor.

Sample,say path of a picture is is `E:\\pics\\labels\\1.jpg`.

Then,your code to add image will be

```
JLabel J0 = new JLabel();
J0.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\pics\\labels\\1.jpg"));
//    ........And SO ON....
```

Comment: The images are saved in the main folder of the project file. In previous programs I did not need to give the file directory if the images were saved there.

Comment: Try the complete path as I suggested and comment as to what you got? Also,if it's in the  `src\default_folder` folder of the project,then obviously you don't need to specify the location.But,try once what I mentioned!

Comment: Also,what do you mean by main folder of the project file? Please write the path of your image location and your java files in the comment in full path from.Ex--->Pictures-C:\\something\\something\\pictures\\picture1.jpg"; 
also,write images as `picture.jpg` rather than `picture.jpeg`,it's a correct pratice!

Comment: I tried using the complete path but it did not make any different.

Comment: @d00by-Try changing `.jpeg` with `.jpg` and also I find only one JLabel in your image.Also,please post path as I mentioned in my previous comment!

Comment: The name of the file is irrelevant, jpg can be called jpeg and is valid and correct practice. It is never good practice to suggest to someone to use an absolute path to image, unless the image is been specified by the user of course, but that's a different matter

Comment: I just realized that I had made a stupid mistake. My image files were ".jpg" and not ".jpeg". I changed the code to use the .jpg extension and it now displays the images. Thanks everyone for your input

Comment: i agree with you @MadProgrammer but,it is really a good habit to use `jpg` rather than `jpeg`,I have read it several times.But,you are correct about it as it won't affect anyways either!